Problem with Index during merge of 2 datasets
I have to dataframe:
df_recap:

and df23:

I have to copy the "Quantity" and "measurement_unit" from df23 into df_recap for this list of code (type of code L2.3). It can be present 2 or more element of the code in df23 (for these case, measurement_unit is unique and quantity is the sum of the values / records).

With this code:
`
# Carica i file CSV
df_semifinal = pd.read_csv('SemiFinal.csv')
df_l23 = pd.read_csv('L23.csv')

# 1. Raggruppa il dataset df_l23 per 'code', somma le quantità e mantiene il valore unico di 'measurement_unit'
df_l23_grouped = df_l23.groupby('code').agg({
    'quantity': 'sum',                   # Somma i valori di 'quantity'
    'measurement_unit': 'first'           # Mantiene il primo valore di 'measurement_unit' (assumendo sia uguale per lo stesso code)
})

# 2. Filtra le righe di df_semifinal dove 'Tipo Voce' è 'L2.3' e le colonne 'Quantità' o 'Unità di misura' sono NaN o '/'
mask = (df_semifinal['Tipo Voce'] == 'L2.3') & (
    df_semifinal['Quantità'].isna() | df_semifinal['Quantità'].eq('/') |
    df_semifinal['Unità di misura'].isna() | df_semifinal['Unità di misura'].eq('/')
)

# 3. Unisci il dataset df_semifinal con df_l23_grouped in base al 'Codice' di df_semifinal e 'code' di df_l23_grouped
df_merged = pd.merge(df_semifinal[mask], df_l23_grouped, left_on='Codice', right_on='code', how='left')

# 4. Sostituisci i valori mancanti o '/' nelle colonne 'Quantità' e 'Unità di misura' con i dati da df_l23_grouped
df_semifinal.loc[mask, 'Quantità'] = df_merged['quantity']
df_semifinal.loc[mask, 'Unità di misura'] = df_merged['measurement_unit']

# 5. Rimuovi eventuali colonne in eccesso come 'code' se non necessarie
df_semifinal.drop(columns=['code'], inplace=True, errors='ignore')

# 6. Salva il dataset aggiornato 
df_semifinal

it seams the there is a problem of index:

the value L2.3 A.01.01.01 should be Quantity = 1 and A.02.01.01 Quantity = 1.36
Thanks
